# How to get Connections of Linkedin profile in android

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am trying to get the **Connections** or user's friends info from **LinkedIn** using LinkedIn  jar for android and example given in [google code](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/AndroidConfiguration), but i wont get Connections using `linkedInApiClient.getConnectionsForCurrentUser()` this method call it returns null, but i can access user current profile info using `linkedInApiClient.getProfileForCurrentUser()`

can any body suggest me how to get User connections information in **linkedIn** in android. Or guide me the the wright way.

Comment: You can get connections of linked in using socialauth android version.<br/>
[Click here to get socialauth android](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the solution for the above ask question, what I was doing wrong, was that we have to pass an argument of the **ProfileField** information we want, like this:

```
final Set<ProfileField> connectionFields = EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.MAIN_ADDRESS,
                ProfileField.PHONE_NUMBERS, ProfileField.LOCATION,
                ProfileField.LOCATION_COUNTRY, ProfileField.LOCATION_NAME,
                ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE,
                ProfileField.INDUSTRY, ProfileField.CURRENT_STATUS,
                ProfileField.CURRENT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP, ProfileField.API_STANDARD_PROFILE_REQUEST,
                ProfileField.EDUCATIONS, ProfileField.PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL, ProfileField.POSITIONS,
                ProfileField.LOCATION, ProfileField.PICTURE_URL);
        Connections connections = client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser(connectionFields);
```

Comment: I m using the shown snippet, but unable to get connection due to permission error in auth token

Comment: so what i have to do for get email address??

Comment: @Animesh Sinha, I ab able to get my all connections using  getConnectionsForCurrentUser() method but don't how to get connections in batching. I tried getConnectionsForCurrentUser(arg0, arg1) method to get connections in batching but couldn't get proper data( some connections are skipped, repeated). I am assuming param 'arg0' as START and 'arg1' as END. Suggest me if i am wrong.